# ARM template for synapse auditing successfully ran but not reflecting the auditing configurations on the azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-rm-template, azure-synapse, auditing

I am using ARM templates to enable auditing of the synapse pool, but though the template runs successfully in CI/CD release pipeline, the changes made aren't reflected on the portal. What could be the possible issue? I already have the required permissions and checked the parameters' values too.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. please take a moment and read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask about how to asking questions also read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example about how to ask a good question with minimum requirement.

Comment: please write a summarized title and put the rest of the explanation in the body. Goodluck 

Comment: How about the result if you deploy the ARM template maually?

Comment: Yeah, manually it is possible. But, I am working on a use-case, which needs automated enabling.